# PowerPoint Interop - Identify Slide Insertion Type - Copied or New

Tags: c#, vba, vb.net, interop, powerpoint

Just wondering if there is any way to identify if a slide is inserted through insert slide feature or via copy slide feature.

I've to do something different if slide is inserted through copy slide feature.

Any hint or workaround would be highly appreciated.

**P.S.** I'm using PowerPoint.Application.PresentationNewSlide event to detect new slide insertion but it's not possible to tell if the newly inserted slide is copied or created.

Comment: what event args does the `PresentationNewSlide` have?

Comment: PowerPoint.Slide object

Comment: Not answers, but a couple questions that might help:  Does the NewSlide event fire *while* a slide is being inserted via insert slide, or does it fire after the insertion is done? You might be able to look for hidden PPT windows/PowerPnt.exe instances to test for uses of insert slide. If the event fires after insertion is complete, then the presence of add'l PPT windows might be a useful thing to watch for.